# get and set <env-entry> from remote client

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, jndi

I have EJB TimeServiceEJB with remote interfce TimeService. In Deploy descriptor of my EJB module there is:

```
<ejb-name>TimeServiceEJB</ejb-name>
...
<env-entry>
    <description>... </description>
    <env-entry-name>variable</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.Integer</env-entry-type>
    <env-entry-value>10</env-entry-value>
</env-entry>
```

I need to get this variable from client application and be able to edit it. I trying to do it this way:

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial", "com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");
p.setProperty("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "com.sun.enterprise.naming");
p.setProperty("java.naming.factory.state", "com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl");
p.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "localhost");
p.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "3700");
InitialContext iniCtx = new InitialContext(p);
Integer variable = (Integer) iniCtx.lookup("java:comp/ejb/TimeServiceEJB/variable");
```

But i got nothing. Tried to lookup in different ways ("java:global/ejb/TimeServiceEJB/variable", "java:comp/env/TimeServiceEJB/variable", "java:global/ear-name/module-name/TimeServiceEJB/) - always had "javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: No object bound for ..."

Tried to set mappingName of this variable by annotaion  @Resource(name="variable", mappedName="env/variable"), and lookup by "env/variable", but got NameNotFoundException.

Is there any ideas, how to get this variable? And the second question is: can i edit its value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any ideas, how to get this variable?

Environment entries are only visible in the application component's naming context (i.e. `java:comp/env` from the `InitialContext` within the EJB or web module where it is declared). (Exception: Java EE 6 provides ways to declare and access module, application, and global-scoped environment entries, but those require specific environment entry prefixes. See EE.5.2.2 from the [Java EE 6 specification](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=316) for more information.)

> And the second question is: can i edit its value?

Environment entry values cannot be modified in JNDI at runtime. I'd suggest exposing a separate method on your EJB that gets and sets this value locally.